# MIT Scheme prompt: indent and up/down arrows

Tags: line-editor

I run Scheme either as: `rlwrap scheme`, option which let's me use up/down left/right arrows, but that disables tab. Or as `scheme` option that let's me indent commands with tab, but disables the arrows.

I want both to be able to type things like:

`(* (+ 3 4)`

`.  (+ 4 6)`

`.  (+ 55 55)`

`.   )`

without typing empty spaces. AND to move to previous command or back and forth with arrows. How can I configure it?

Comment: You might find more scheme users at stackoverflow

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but you can enter a tab char to readline using the literal-next prefix, control-V tab. (see man stty for lnext).

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you'll find a line-based command line interface that caters for indentation. Line editors are primarily designed to handle line-by-line input, for which indentation is not a concern.

You can get a more comfortable interface by running [MIT Scheme in Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/GNU-Emacs-Interface.html). From emacs, type `M-x run-scheme RET`. Then you benefit from all of Emacs's editing capabilities and configurability.